# simple Help with two bevels and boolean

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a simple shape with a bevel modifier making the edges smooth (using weights). I added a boolean modifier cutting 4 holes in the shape. I want those holes to have a bevel as well (less than the first bevel). I try adding another bevel modifier after the boolean so that I can bevel those edges. No matter what I adjust, I can't get the bevel to work on those holes. [image: image of what I mean]

Comment: I think you might have to apply the boolean before you can edit the bevel

Answer (score 4):

*Bevel modifier* limited by *Weight* doesn't work when it's after *Boolean Modifier* in the modifier stack.
This applies to all edges, not only the new ones.

To bevel edges made by Boolean, you can use *Angle limit*.

[image]